# How to parse complete f32 with nom?

Tags: floating-point, rust, nom

There is a function [`float_s`](https://docs.rs/nom/4.0.0/nom/fn.float_s.html) that parses floats in stream mod (can return `Incomplete`). I want to use `CompleteStr` as input type instead. How I can achieve that?

Simple approach fails with complains about `&str` and `CompleteStr` mismatches:

```
named!(parse_float_complete(CompleteStr) -> f32,
    ws!(::num::float_s)
);
```

I'm using `nom 4.0.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nom v4.1.0` fixed this problem:

- `float` and `double` now work on all of nom's input types (`&[u8]`, `&str`, `CompleteByteSlice`, `CompleteStr` and any type that implements the required traits). `float_s` and `double_s` got the same modification, but are now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

`float_s` expects a string, so you have to extract the string from the `CompleteStr`:

```
named!(parse_float_complete(CompleteStr) -> f32,
    ws!(call!(|input| ::num::float_s(input.0).map(|output, result| CompleteStr(output, result))))
);
```

Comment: It should be `call!(|input: CompleteStr| ::nom::float_s(input.0).map(|(output, result)| (CompleteStr(output), result)))`, but you need to map `Err` part too, so it's very unpractical solution.

Comment: And I understand that I can unwrap-wrap input and output. I'm just hoping that there is some less cumbersome solution.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to just copy-paste `float_s` implementation:

```
fn float_cs(input: CompleteStr) -> ::nom::IResult<CompleteStr, f32> {
  flat_map!(input, call!(::nom::recognize_float), parse_to!(f32))
}
```